# Splitting responses (as numbers) into multiple columns

Tags: r

I've survey results (categorical) stored in csv file with multiple responses within the same cell. I'd like to split it into separate column (dummy variables)

The data looks like

```
response <-c(1,2,3,123)
df <-data.frame(response)
```

I tried the code below

```
for(t in unique(df$response))
{df[paste("response",t,sep="")] <- ifelse(df$response==t,1,0)}
```

the result is here, but it created a new column for 123

```
head(df)
response response1 response2 response3 response123
1        1         1         0         0           0
2        2         0         1         0           0
3        3         0         0         1           0
4      123         0         0         0           1
```

I'd like the data to look as below

```
response response1 response2 response3
1        1         1         0         0
2        2         0         1         0
3        3         0         0         1
4      123         1         1         1
```

Appreciate your help and advice :)

Comment: `cbind(df, model.matrix(~factor(response)-1, df))` then reset the names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do

```
df1 <- cbind(df, +(sapply(1:3, grepl, x = df$response)))
colnames(df1)[-1] <- paste0("response", colnames(df1)[-1])
df1
#   response response1 response2 response3
#1        1         1         0         0
#2        2         0         1         0
#3        3         0         0         1
#4      123         1         1         1
```

Comment: Would you please let me know if there's a way to include it in the same df? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Omar Then just update the `df` object i.e. `df <- cbind(df, +(sapply(1:3, grepl, x = df$response)))`